# How to connect to 2 sites with PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl

How can I get source code of few sites using cURL?
I tried something like this

```
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$linki = $_POST['linki'];
$link = explode("\n", $linki);
$html=array();
foreach($link as $x){
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $x);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $txt = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);
    $html[] = str_get_html($txt);   
}
foreach($html as $dupa){
    echo "<div class='asd'>" . $dupa . "</div>";
}
```

but it gives me source code only from last link

Comment: Because your setting the HTML array each time you visit a site (assignment). You either need a multi dimensional array for each site or another type of structure. Or run the outside code inside your first for loop

Comment: when i try to echo $txt or $html in first loop it still show only last site